# How to get data from the Model and update it

Tags: swift, swiftui, observable, data-modeling, swift5

I have a data model that I want to use its data in various views. So firstly I have problem polling that information from my data model and secondly I have problem to update the data.
Here in one example of my data model with three views.

**Data Model**

```
// A basic resocrd of each exercise in a workout
class WorkoutItem:ObservableObject, Identifiable{
    
    var id:Int = 0
    var name: String = "An Exercise"
    var sets:Int = 3
    var reps:Int = 10
    
    func addSet() {
        sets += 1
    }
    init(){
        
    }
    
}

// The model for holding a workout
class WorkoutModel:ObservableObject{
    @Published var workout:[WorkoutItem] =  []
    var lastID:Int = -1
    
    /// Creates a newID based on the last known ID
    private func newId()->Int{
        lastID += 1
        return lastID
    }
    
    func add(name:String, sets:Int, reps:Int){
        let newExercise = WorkoutItem()
        
        workout += [newExercise]
    }
    
    
    init() {
        add(name: "Psuh Pp", sets: 1, reps: 8)
        add(name: "Pull UPs", sets: 1, reps: 10)
    }
}
```

**View 1**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var myWorkout: WorkoutModel
    var body: some View {
        List(self.myWorkout.workout) { item in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.name).font(.headline)
                    ExerciseEntryView(exItem: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View 2**

```
struct ExerciseEntryView: View {
    var exItem: WorkoutItem
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                
                ForEach(0 ..< exItem.sets, id: \.self){ row in
                    ExerciseEntryView_Row(setNumber: row)
                }
                
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.exItem.addSet()
            }) {
                Text("Add Set").foregroundColor(Color.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View 3**

```
struct ExerciseEntryView_Row: View {
    var setNumber: Int
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("Set Number \(setNumber)")
        }
    }
}
```

Firstly when running the code, as you can see in the below image the title is still the default value ('An Exercise') while it should `Pull up` and `Push up`.  Also when I press on `add set` the set gets updated in the terminal but it does not update the view.

Any idea why this is not functioning?

Thanks in advance.
[image: Screenshot of the app]

Answer (score 0):

First you can make your `WorkoutItem` a *struct*:

```
struct WorkoutItem: Identifiable {
    var id: Int = 0
    var name: String = "An Exercise"
    var sets: Int = 3
    var reps: Int = 10

    mutating func addSet() {
        sets += 1
    }
}
```

Then in the `WorkoutModel` you weren't using setting any properties for the new exercise:

```
class WorkoutModel: ObservableObject {
    ...
    func add(name: String, sets: Int, reps: Int) {
        var newExercise = WorkoutItem()
        newExercise.name = name // <- set properties
        newExercise.sets = sets
        newExercise.reps = reps

        workout += [newExercise]
    }

    init() {
        add(name: "Push Pp", sets: 1, reps: 8)
        add(name: "Pull UPs", sets: 1, reps: 10)
    }
}
```